# column name with brackets or other punctuations for dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an imported data frame that has column names with various punctuations including parentheses, e.g. `BILLNG.STATUS.(COMPLETED./.INCOMPLTE)` .

I was trying to use `group_by` from `dplyr` to do some summarizing, something like

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ORDER.NO, BILLNG.STATUS.(COMPLETED./.INCOMPLTE))
```

which brings the error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  could not find function "BILLNG.STATUS."`

Short of changing the column names, is there a way to handle such column names directly in `group_by` ?

Comment: The periods are legal but the slash (division operator) and parentheses are not. You may need to enclose the name in quotes. You might consider a different process for importing your data or attention to building valid column names immediately after importation.

Comment: Yup IRL I scrubbed clean the column names. I'm more interested if there is a way that `dplyr` can handle the parentheses and slash, or it's a limitation to skirt around with other pre-processing.

Comment: I tried all the ways I could think of and kept getting errors

Comment: Have you tried `group_by_("ORDER.NO, BILLNG.STATUS.(COMPLETED./.INCOMPLTE")`?

Comment: @RichardScriven that didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can make this work if you enclose the "illegal" column names in backticks. For example, let's say I start with this data frame (called `df`):

```
  BILLING.STATUS.(COMPLETED./.INCOMPLETE) ORDER.VALUE.(USD)
1                                       A        0.01544196
2                                       A        0.95522706
3                                       B        1.13479303
4                                       B        1.22848285
```

Then I can summarise it like this:

```
dat %>% group_by(`BILLING.STATUS.(COMPLETED./.INCOMPLETE)`) %>% 
  summarise(count=n(),
            mean = mean(`ORDER.VALUE.(USD)`))
```

Giving:

```
  BILLING.STATUS.(COMPLETED./.INCOMPLETE) count      mean
1                                       A     2 0.4853345
2                                       B     2 1.1816379
```

Backticks also come in handy for referring to or creating variable names with whitespace. You can find a number of questions related to `dplyr` and backticks on SO, and there's also some discussion of backticks in the help for `Quotes`.

Comment: Thank you, this works for both `group_by` and `select`.

I stumble when I take it further into a formula in `summarise` i.e. `orders.n %>% group_by(ORDER.NO) %>% summarize(total=sum(`ORDER.VALUE.(USD)`))` , which understandably causes error `Error in sum("1603") : invalid 'type' (character) of argument` . But that's beyond the scope of this question already I guess.

Comment: And the above shows how I don't know how to enclose backticks in backticks on SO (see unshaded ORDER.VALUE.(USD) )...

Comment: I don't get an error as long the illegal variable names are enclosed in backticks. I've updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just using this not-an-answer as a counter-example or illustration of  limitations for the the backtick method. (It was the first strategem I tried. Perhaps it is the fact that two language operations ("(" and "/") are being handled adjacently that makes this fail.)

```
names(iris)[5] <- "Specie(/)s"
library(dplyr)
by_species <- iris %>% group_by(`Specie(/)s`)
by_species %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
#Error: cannot modify grouping variable
```

Tried a variety or other language-oriented efforts with `quote`, `as.name` and `substitute` that also failed. (I wish there were a mechanism to request that this sink to the bottom of the answers.)

Comment: I get the same error when I try summarise_each on the data frame I used in my answer. I'm wondering if that fails not because of the particular illegal character(s) you used, but because the `.` pronoun isn't set up to handle illegal column names.