# renaming columns in R with `-` symbol

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rename

```
temp <- data.frame(re_ply = rnorm(10), total_ID = rnorm(10),  re_ask = rnorm(10))
```

I want to change the column as:
`re_ply` to `Re-ply`
`total_ID` to `total_id`
`re_ask` to `Re-ask`

```
temp <- temp %>% dplyr::rename(Re-ply = re_ply,
                           total_id = total_ID,
                           Re-ask = re_ask)
```

This won't work since in `Re-ply` and `Re-ask` has the `-` symbol won't work. How can I fix it. I know it is not ideal to have a `-` symbol in the column name but just wanted to check if this is possible at all. My only goal is to rename this file as shown above, write it out as `.csv` and do other processing in excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a single column in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [column name with brackets or other punctuations for dplyr group\_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162555/column-name-with-brackets-or-other-punctuations-for-dplyr-group-by)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using `rename`. You just have to put the column names with special charcters inside the "`" sign:

```
temp <- temp %>% dplyr::rename(`Re-ply` = re_ply,
                                total_id = total_ID,
                                `Re-ask` = re_ask)
names(temp)
[1] "Re-ply"   "total_id" "Re-ask"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, wrap all argument-names with "special chars" (like minus) in backticks or quotes, e.g. `rename("Re-ply" = re_ply)`. And you can use quasiquotation, or `sjmisc::var_rename()` if you want *old name = new name* instead *new name = old name*.

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)

temp <- data.frame(
  re_ply = rnorm(10), 
  total_ID = rnorm(10),  
  re_ask = rnorm(10)
)


old_name <- "re_ply"
new_name <- "Re-ply"

temp %>% colnames()
#> [1] "re_ply"   "total_ID" "re_ask"

temp %>% 
  dplyr::rename(
    "Re-Ply" = re_ply,
    total_id = total_ID,
    "Re-ask" = re_ask
  ) %>% 
  colnames()
#> [1] "Re-Ply"   "total_id" "Re-ask"

temp %>% 
  dplyr::rename(
    !! new_name := !! old_name,
    total_id = total_ID,
    "Re-ask" = re_ask
  ) %>% 
  colnames()
#> [1] "Re-ply"   "total_id" "Re-ask"

temp %>% 
  sjmisc::var_rename(
    re_ply = "Re-ply",
    total_ID = total_id,
    re_ask = "Re-ask"
  ) %>% 
  colnames()
#> [1] "Re-ply"   "total_id" "Re-ask"

temp %>% 
  sjmisc::var_rename(
    !! old_name := !! new_name,
    total_ID = "total_id",
    re_ask = "Re-ask"
  ) %>% 
  colnames()
#> [1] "Re-ply"   "total_id" "Re-ask"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: R allows using regular quotes here but the documentation recommends against doing so (it’s incredibly confusing because the resulting token isn’t treated as a character string by the R interpreter; R only supports it for reasons of backwards compatibility).